# How to stop Visual Studio debugger from stepping into assembly?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008

How to stop Visual Studio debugger from stepping into assembly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Uncheck **Tools->Options->Debugging->Enable address-level debugging->Show disassembly if source not available**

Comment: I have the same problem. Unchecking the mentioned boxes does not prevent it.

Comment: You can also try checking "Just My Code" if this does not work.

Comment: where is tools setting? I tried to search in setting/preference, but cannot find it

Comment: found it, for me it is under LLDB settings

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the source?

[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx)